# Pass an array of value to bash script to use as argument

Tags: bash

This is a command I have inside my bash script. It requires multiple --region argument and I would like to pass an array of argument like `['us-east-1', 'us-west-1']`

```
custodian run -s out --region us-east-1 --region us-west-1 policy.yml
```

How can I code out in a way where the bash script will loop through the array and generate `--region us-east-1` and `--region us-west-1` and then insert in the command? I am not able to know the size of the array and it might be 2 items or 5 items.

What I have achieved is passing an argument to the bash script and get the value using `$1`

Comment: So `['us-east-1', 'us-west-1']` is coming from a json file?

Comment: I am passing it from my nodejs application as an argument using child proccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can this achieve what you wanted to do ?

```
custodian run -s out ${@/#/--region } policy.yml
```

calling method :

```
bash test.sh us-east-1 us-west-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that might do what you want.

To extract only the pattern that you want.

```
echo "['us-east-1', 'us-west-1', 'us-south-1']" | grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]-]+'
```

Output

```
us-east-1
us-west-1
us-south-1
```

If the input is coming from the `.yml` file

```
mapfile -t array < <(grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]-]+' policy.yml)
```

---

To save that in an array using `mapfile`

```
mapfile -t array < <(echo "['us-east-1', 'us-west-1', 'us-south-1']" | grep -Eo "[[:alnum:]-]+")
```

To add the `--region` in front of each element in the array.

```
"${array[@]/#/--region }"
```

```
echo "${array[@]/#/--region }"
```

output

```
-region us-east-1 --region us-west-1 --region us-south-1
```

To add all the commands

```
echo custodian run -s out "${array[@]/#/--region }" policy.yml
```

Output

```
custodian run -s out --region us-east-1 --region us-west-1 --region us-south-1 policy.yml
```

The problem with that approach is that both `--region us-west` is one argument.

If that does not work you will need to loop through the array and add the `--region` on every element.

Something like.

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
  options+=(--region "$i")
done
```

And then run the commands all together.

```
echo custodian run -s out "${options[@]}" policy.yml
```

Output

```
custodian run -s out --region us-east-1 --region us-west-1 --region us-south-1 policy.yml
```

- Remove the `echo` to execute the commands and not just output to `stdout`

Comment: When I run this line, `echo custodian run -s out "${options[@]}" policy.yml`, I am only able to see `--region` and then nothing at the end of the command.

I've printed out echo and it returns `--region ap-southeast-1 --region us-east-2`. It seems like it only prints out the first item of the array